# URL Rewrite Rule to ByPass IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have URL Rewrite rule in IIS 10 to enforce all http request to https this way and it works perfect.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Here comes the twist..
I am hosting one ClickOnce application on the same server and when installer try to download the application then it gives error 
**URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697202' Error: An error occurred trying to download**

Although URL is propery accessed via browser which is mentioned in this error.

As per microsoft documents error description is

**if the setup URL of the ClickOnce application being installed is redirected from a non-secure to a secure site (or vice-versa), the installation will fail because the Internet Explorer warning interrupts it.**

** Installer is using IE internally to download the manifest file

Now to tackle this situation I have made IP binding with my site in IIS so i would access the file with IP but when I do access the site with IP then the above rule also trigger for it and redirects to HTTPS and browser give an error again because hostname mismatch in SSL Certs. I want to bypass this redirect rule for my site when it browsed with IP.

I donot know how I can modify the above rule by having additional condition or what will be the new rule to bypass this https redirection when access via IP.

EDIT: https://dpaste.de/xWJE Here is full webconfig with suggested fix by @Kul Tgin